# Alerting JS Array Selection

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a select with options that I am putting into an array, and I am attempting to alert a specific message when you click a button, but only if the proper array[x] has been selected. However, when I click the button, regardless of the option I get the message.  What am I doing wrong?

Code:

HTML:

```
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
<br />
<br />
<select id = "list" value = "list">
   <option id="one" value="one">
   one
   </option>

   <option id="two" value="two">
   two
   </option>

   <option id="three" value="three">
   three
   </option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var listArr = [];
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var list = document.getElementById("list");
var selected = document.getElementById("list").selectedIndex;

for (var i = 0; i < list.options.length; i++) {
    listArr[i] = list.options[i].value;
}

button.onclick = function() {
    if (selected = [1]) {
        alert("hello");
    }
};
```

Comment: What is with the `if(selected=[1]){...}` statement ?

Comment: Your if is wrong, maybe you wanted it to be `if(selected === listArr[1])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot compare arrays like this. You need to use literal number instead. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9do0pb3o/)

```
var listArr = [];
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var list = document.getElementById("list");
var selected = document.getElementById("list");

for(var i = 0; i < list.options.length; i++) {
  listArr[i] = list.options[i].value;
}

button.onclick = function() {
  if(selected.selectedIndex == 1) {
    alert('hello');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, you need the updated value of the select:

```
button.onclick = function()
{
  if(document.getElementById("list").selectedIndex==1) // Also change = to ==
   {
   alert("hello");
   }
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6bs1vjva/1/